# Selenium Webdriver - sendKeys() not sending all keys - Java

Tags: java, selenium

I use Selenium Webdriver with Java and I've found a problem. When I try to send some text to the textfield, it only sends first char of two. I tried setting it with JavaScriptExecutor, but same thing happened. ChromeDriver is running and working fine. Code below:

```
    public void sendNumberToChrome (int number){
        textfield.clear(); //  textfield is already set, it's classic input field with max. 10 characters
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(number)); // This prints for example 94
        textfield.sendKeys(String.valueOf(number)); // But only "9" appears in the browser
    }
```

I also tried to send it character by character:

```
String[] arr = String.valueOf(number).split("(?<!^)");  // splits number character by character
for (String s : arr){
    System.out.println(s); // Prints 9 and then 4
    textfield.sendKeys(s); // Also only 9 appears
    Thread.sleep(100); // Maybe browser can not work too fast, so I will wait before sending next character
}
```

JavascriptExecutor also send only one character and every few minutes crashes (don't know why), so I am not using it.
But what is interesting - when I do this:

```
textfield.sendKeys(String.valueOf(94));
```

It sends 94 to Chrome! I don't know where the problem is, can someone help me?

EDIT: Chrome version: 29.0.1547.76 m, Selenium Server Standalone 2.35.0, Chromedriver v2.3

Comment: What version of Chrome/ChromeDriver/Selenium? Any different with another browser?

Comment: All is fine, when I type exactly what I want to send, it sends it. But it refuses to send the variable, although SOMETIMES it sends both characters...

Answer (score 1):

Javascript on the page is messing with your input

try this code

```
static boolean sendKeyIntoElement(WebElement webElement, String value){
    webElement.click();
    webElement.sendKeys(value);

    while(!webElement.getAttribute("value").equals(value)){
        webElement.click();
        webElement.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "a");
        webElement.sendKeys(Keys.DELETE);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return webElement.getAttribute("value").equals(value);
}
```